# Does the constant timer really add a time beetween each request?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I create a simple test plan with :

- a thread group
- a HTTP sampler executing a GET request

My server logs the entry in the controler and the logs contain the log time.

I define 3 users (id threads) and the loop count value is 2.

I try to add a constant timer at the thread group level and at the sampler level and observe the time of logs.

I conclude that the timer add a time after each loop and not after each request as the documentation explains.

Do I miss something ? Do you know how to add a timer after each request ?

The version of JMeter is 5.6.2

To add some details, here are :

- a sample of the logs
- an image showing the thread group
- an image showing the constant timer, the thread delay is 5 000 ms

The first three logs occured at the same second, the next three five seconds later. So the timer is processed after each loop but not after each request.

```
2024-02-22 22:29:31.724  INFO 19108 --- [http-nio-80-exec-1]    : Entry, user=1
2024-02-22 22:29:31.724  INFO 19108 --- [http-nio-80-exec-4]    : Entry, user=3
2024-02-22 22:29:31.724  INFO 19108 --- [http-nio-80-exec-3]    : Entry, user=2
2024-02-22 22:29:36.771  INFO 19108 --- [http-nio-80-exec-6]    : Entry, user=1
2024-02-22 22:29:36.771  INFO 19108 --- [http-nio-80-exec-2]    : Entry, user=2
2024-02-22 22:29:36.771  INFO 19108 --- [http-nio-80-exec-5]    : Entry, user=3
```

[image: Thread group]

[image: Constant timer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) "explains" that

> timers are processed before each sampler in the scope in which they are found

Refer to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) article to learn more about the "scope".

In short:

- If you add a Constant Timer on Thread Group level - it will create a delay before each Sampler in the Thread Group
- If you add a Constant Timer as a child of a specific Sampler - it will create a delay before this Sampler only

If you want to introcude a delay at a specific place - consider using [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) Sampler instead

More information: [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer)

Comment: I agree that's the documentation descirbes but this is not what i observed in my logs. I edited my question to add some details about logs and the test plan.

Comment: In fact I get it, the timer simulates the think time of a user, so each user performs his request, then think - wait and performs the other request. So that's logic. Thanks for your help @Ivan